# How to stop xcode from adjusting text font while typing?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I type something in the editor, the text font of that line of code is changed until I stop typing for a few seconds.

In the following screenshot, I tried deleting some text at line 711. You can see that the text font of that line is different from the other.

The moment I start typing, the text font of that line changes. After I stop typing for a few seconds, the font is back to normal.

My question: How could I stop this bug (It's a bug to me)?

Thank you


[image]

Comment: Go through all font settings in you selected theme and make sure they are the same height.

Comment: @Gereon Thanks for your answer. It works for the font size. How about the color? How could I keep it unchanged? In other word, imagine typing doesn't trigger the change.

Comment: The whole point of themes is that colors represent different kinds of pieces of your code, so unless you define a theme that only uses one color, colors will always change according to what a particular piece of text is.